# How to solve an inequality for a arbitrary variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to prove the inequality 
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}>\frac{1}{n+1}\quad \forall \ n>1.$$ How would I go about doing this? I've tried solving it on my own but my final answer is $1>0$.

Comment: How exactly would that prove the inequality? Wouldn't I need to get n>1?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $n+1>0$ we get
$\frac{n+1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}>1$ and this is
$$(n+1)^2-n>n(n+1)$$ this is $$n^2+n+1>n^2+n$$ or $1>0$
all steps are back wards possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{n+1}>0.$$ Simplifying LHS gives $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac1n-\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2-n(n+2)}{n(n+1)^2}.$$ Since the denominator is positive, it only suffices to show that the numerator is positive too. Pursuing this by expanding gives $$(n+1)^2-n(n+2)=n^2+2n+1-n^2-2n=1>0,$$ as desired.